# SharedPreferences not persistent

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I am using a **SharedPreferences** in Android.Everything works great in the same session.

However once I relaunch the application, all of the preferences that were set from the previous **session** are lost.

Is there anything I need to specify to tell the **SharedPreferences** to hang around from run to run?

I am creating the preferences by calling

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Then I set properties by e.g.

```
preferences.edit().putString(key, value);
```

and I get it by

```
preferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
```

Thanks, 
Victor

Comment: have u written editor.commit() ?

Comment: If you're `Set<String` isn't saving between app sessions it's because of a bug. Use this workaround:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26315757/2371425.

Comment: Thank You sooo much Sakiboy. I lost almost 4 hours trying to figure out why after calling commit, and verifying changes while still in the same context, but then switching to another context and the Value I updated reverted back to the old Value. Android please document this stuff and do your job so I can do mine please. 4 hours wasted at the cpu because for some reason Android/Google has poor documentation...geez!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

SharedPreferences are persistent accross relaunch, restart, I think the problem is you are not commiting the preferences, use following to store values in preferences:

```
Preferences.Editor edit=preferences.edit();
edit.putString(key, value);
edit.commit();
```

Comment: `apply()` is better than `commit()` as it allows the writing to occur in the background

Answer (score 24):

You're likely not committing your changes. Set properties like so

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Without the commit you're farting in the wind.

Comment: That escalated quickly :D

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me please try:

```
private SharedPreferences mShared;
private Editor mEdit;
mShared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

mEdit = mShared.edit();
mEdit.putString(key, value);
mEdit.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

to get value in pref

```
SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean silent = pref1.getString("silentMode", "...");
```

to save vlue use onstoe or onPause methds

```
SharedPreferences pref2 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref2.edit();
editor.putString("silentMode", "...");
```

That works for me fine and healthy

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for API level ? and above then you should be using `editor.apply()` instead of `editor.commit()` when programatically modifying your preferences. `editor.commit()` has been deprecated, and `editor.apply()` will handle the actual persistence in the background, which `editor.commit()` does not do.

Note that `editor.apply()`, if it fails, does so silently.

Comment: This is just wrong: commit() is not deprecated at all. The only notice in API 22 is: If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from your application's main thread, consider using {@link #apply} instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works for me.

```
package com.example.persistence;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String NOTE_PREFS="note";
SharedPreferences msgSettings;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     msgSettings = getSharedPreferences(NOTE_PREFS,0);

      EditText et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      if (msgSettings.contains(NOTE_PREFS)) {
            et.setText(msgSettings.getString(
                    NOTE_PREFS, "my note")); 

    }

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
      EditText et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      String b = et.getText().toString();
      Editor editor = msgSettings.edit();
      editor.putString(NOTE_PREFS,b);
        editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
     EditText et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      String b = et.getText().toString();
      Editor editor = msgSettings.edit();
      editor.putString(NOTE_PREFS,b);
        editor.commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferences will not be saved until you commit them, i.e.:

```
// DON'T DO THIS... See Next Example
preferences.edit().putString(key, value);
preferences.edit().commit();
```

**EDIT**: The above has a subtle bug (from comments); you need to keep reference to the editor object, otherwise the above example that commits the value will create a new instance. Should be:

```
Preferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString(key, value);
edit.commit();
```

For reference, from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29):

> Note that you must call [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) to have any changes you perform in
>   the Editor actually show up in the SharedPreferences.

Comment: This code is wrong since you are commiting in a different Editor instance than the one you've put the String.

Comment: @ffleandro - if this code is wrong, then so is every other answer to this question.

Comment: no man, I've seen lots of correct answers. The problem with your answer is that when you call `preferences.edit()` you are creating a `SharedPreferences.Editor` object. When you `commit` you are commiting in a different instance than the one you've called `putString`, hence it will not persist. I recommend you read again the `docs` you posted.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time has been past but you may use

```
.apply()
```

instead of

```
.commit()
```

that would be better. commit tries to write immediately but apply is asynchronous. here are the explanation from google docs

*Unlike commit, which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit while a apply is still outstanding, the commit will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.*