# Why shared preference commit fails?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my android service I have action user present registered which writes a String value to default shared preference. Meanwhile I have another function in the service which writes a Hashset to shared preference. I have used commit in both cases.

On user present action :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().putString("abc", udata).commit();
```

On onother function :

```
if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().putStringSet("si",ssetdata).commit())
```

Some times second writing fails   why ? Is it because

"Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call commit wins. "

Comment: I removed the string set , commited and then added again. It worked all time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820252/android-string-set-preference-is-not-persistent?lq=1 question answered by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1150712/zhangxaochen helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Use apply for the first and commit to the second might help like related below:

*Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.*

[Read more here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Answer (score 1):

Is your service running in a separate process? (see the `android:process` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml`)

If so, you have to open the `SharedPreferences` using `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`.

Comment: No. I am using the same process.

Answer (score 0):

try to call your `SharedPreference` **just once**, and then use `editor` to commit your data:

```
                SharedPreference SP;
                SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                editor = SP.edit();

                //...
                    editor.putString("abc", udata);
                    editor.commit();
                //...
                    editor.putStringSet("si",ssetdata)
                    editor.commit()
```