# Set<String> in android sharedpreferences does not save on force close

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Im trying to use androids sharedpreferences, I´ve logged everything and the code below really commits the string set. The problem is when I force close the app and start again, the settings.getStringSet returns an empty set. No errormessages anywhere.

I´ve tried PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences but that does not work for me either.

Thanks for you time.

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private static final String FOLLOWED_ROUTES = "followedRoutes";
```

and later on when saved is called:

```
public void onFollowClicked(View view){

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

Set<String> follows =  settings.getStringSet(FOLLOWED_ROUTES, new HashSet<String>());
follows.add(routeId);

editor.putStringSet(FOLLOWED_ROUTES, follows);
editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: Do you respect the life cycle? In which state you save your data?

Comment: everyting is saved before I force quit.

the issue is that settings.getStringSet(... does not returns the values I commited to it.

I´ve also tried replacing commit() to apply() - no success

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

Also for refference:

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

**EDIT:**

There's actually a bug with this one, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27801). An extract from there:

> This problem is still present on the 17 API level.
>
> It is caused because the getStringSet() method of the
>   SharedPreferences class doesn't return a copy of the Set object: it
>   returns the entire object and, when you add new elements to it, the
>   commitToMemory method of the SharedPrefencesImpl.EditorImpl class see
>   that the existing value is equal to the previous one stored.
>
> The ways to workaround this issue is to make a copy of the Set
>   returned by SharedPreferences.getStringSet or force the write to
>   memory using other preference that always change (for example, a
>   property that stores the size of the set each time)

**EDIT2:**

There might be a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android), take a look.

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type Set<String>, since set is just an interface

Comment: Just a question, whats your minSDK in the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: it works fine if I use a string, but not a stringSet, and that is what I need. I´ve also tried: 
HashSet<String> follows =  (HashSet<String>) settings.getStringSet(FOLLOWED_ROUTES, new HashSet<String>());

Comment: I edited my response. There's a bug with this usage and they have provided a workaround, or sort of ..

Comment: The solution, as provided in your link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android) worked!

As you said, this is a bug. getStringSet() method of the SharedPreferences does not return a copy of the Set object. 

Using JSONArray in combination with the getString() was how I solved the problem

Comment: Your answer is correct. I was trying to save Set<String> in SharedPrefrences and it was not saving at all or saving after some time and NOT instantly - despite using `sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("favs", set).commit();`  Instead of saving "set" I ended up saving `set = new HashSet<>(set);` which solved the problem

Comment: Make a copy of the Set that return and save the copy solve the problem!!!

Answer (score 35):

You can also work around the bug mentioned by g00dy this way:

Get the set from sharedPreferences and save it in a variable.

Then just delete the set in sharedpreferences before adding it again when saving.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
editor.remove("mSet");
editor.apply(); 
editor.putStringSet("mSet", mSet);
editor.apply();
```

Make sure to use apply() or commit() twice.

Alternatively, if you are working in Kotlin simply :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
    .edit {
        this.remove("mSet")
        this.apply()
        this.putStringSet("mSet", mSet)
    }
```

Comment: This saved my life, wish it was better documented.

Comment: Thank You so much I thought I was going crazy. Android please fix this or at least document that it's a problem! Thank You

Comment: OMG awesome fix ! I was starting to give up

Comment: Must be accepted answer. This save my day!. Thanks!