# Expo get unique device id without ejecting

Tags: android, react-native, expo

[This library](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#example) allows you to get unique device id / Mac address of Android devices, which doesn't change after reinstallation.

`Expo.Constants.deviceId` changes after every reinstallation (even if the app version number is the same).

Is there a way to get an unique id for Android that doesn't change after reinstallation (at least for if it's the same version), without ejecting?

Comment: Does Expo.Constants work both on iOS and Android standalone apps?

Comment: @JeafGilbert yes :D

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: You can find more information about that topic in the Github issue. Looks like this is for privacy reasons not wanted. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/825

Comment: does https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid not provide exactly this?

Comment: Yes, but that requires ejecting from Expo (in the old ejection days).

Comment: `react-native-device-info` will usually not work with Expo unless your using the expo barebone app.

Answer (score 29):

For Expo IOS theres currently very limited options, Since Apple forbids getting private device info. We will need to create our own unique identifier below.

**Solution:**

My solution is a combination of [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) and Expo [SecureStore](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) works for IOS and Android.

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


let uuid = uuidv4();
await SecureStore.setItemAsync('secure_deviceid', JSON.stringify(uuid));
let fetchUUID = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('secure_deviceid');
console.log(fetchUUID)
```

This solution will work even if app gets reinstalled, or if user switches devices and copy's all data to new device.
(`Expo.Constants.deviceId` is deprecated and will be removed in Expo SDK 44).

**Full Example:**

To check if you already stored the [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) in [SecureStore](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

let uuid = uuidv4();
let fetchUUID = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('secure_deviceid');
  //if user has already signed up prior
  if (fetchUUID) {
    uuid = fetchUUID
  }
await SecureStore.setItemAsync('secure_deviceid', JSON.stringify(uuid));
console.log(uuid)
```

Comment: I guess the 'secure_deviceid'  kept after app updates but not between installs ?

Comment: It will be kept even for reinstalls since `SecureStore` is stored to the system keychain and according to Expo docs will be kept around "data stored with expo-secure-store can persist across app installs".  

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

Comment: Will it persist between app installs on Android too?
Doc says: Please note that for iOS standalone apps, data stored with expo-secure-store can persist across app installs.

But nothing is mentionned for Android

Comment: @yemd `SecureStore` for Android is stored in `SharedPreferences` this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650870/sharedpreferences-values-do-not-persist

Comment: it give different values each time for same device I need to implement same unique id for one device

Comment: @IbadUrRehman `uuid` gives a new unique id each time called. 
for your case you will need to check if theres already a uuid first and retrieve from `SecureStore`.

Comment: the docs say that it will persist on iOS specifically, which implies that it wont for android

Answer (score 8):

Use `Application.androidId` from expo-application. Id will not change after reinstall or update. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/application/#applicationandroidid

Example:

```
import * as Application from 'expo-application';
import { Platform } from 'expo-modules-core';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const getDeviceId = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    return Application.androidId;
  } else {
    let deviceId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('deviceId');

    if (!deviceId) {
      deviceId = Constants.deviceId; //or generate uuid
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync('deviceId', deviceId);
    }

    return deviceId;
  }
}
```

Comment: but what about ios? It says it will return null on ios. I need something that works on both platform

Comment: @AbhishekAnand i added an example

Comment: For iOS we an use this https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/application/#applicationgetiosidforvendorasync

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do is use `ANDROID_ID` for android or `IDFV` for iOS.

For Expo here is package: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/application/#applicationgetiosidforvendorasync

My code:

```
const newUniqueId = Platform.OS === 'android'
            ? Application.androidId ?? uuid.v4().toString()
            : await Application.getIosIdForVendorAsync() ?? uuid.v4().toString();

let uniqueId = null;
try {
    uniqueId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('uniqueId');
} catch (error) {
    LoggerService.logToSentry(error);
}

try {
    if (!uniqueId) {
        uniqueId = newUniqueId;
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync('uniqueId', uniqueId);
    }
} catch (error) {
    uniqueId = newUniqueId;
    LoggerService.logToSentry(error);
}

return uniqueId;
```

If some one use only `uuid.v4()` and stores with `SecureStore` after app deletion all data will be deleted except `iOS` phones. On Android all `App` data will be deleted with stored keys

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can use facebook module for this purpose.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook-ads/#currentdevicehash

Not sure what happens under hood - but looks like it unique between app reinstal, device restart etc.

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your answer instead of linking to external sources

Answer (score -2):

Just use getuniqueid() method from react-native-device-info. Works on iOS and android to uniquely identify a device .

Comment: This won't work in the Expo managed workflow

Answer (score -2):

To get the device UniqueId in expo project,

1. `npm install react-native-device-info`
2. `expo run:ios` or `expo run:android`

Please note: `expo start` will throw an error

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you would need to eject expo app to use `react-native-device-info`