# how to get deviceId, deviceToken, deviceType in react-native/expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use deviceId, deviceToken, deviceType for the login purpose so how do I get it.
Can someone please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: nothing as I can't get any perfect solution to get that.

Comment: `deviceId` is deprecated and will be removed in Expo SDK 44, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553627/7944610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.GET DEVICE ID:**
  
To get the device information in React Native will use the [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) library. **getDeviceId()** is method for getting id.
For example code:[doc](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-device-info/)

**2.GET DEVICE TYPE:**

**Using the Platform module:**

React Native provides a module that detects the platform in which the app is running. You can use the detection logic to implement platform-specific code. Use this option when only small parts of a component are platform-specific.

```
import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 200 : 100,
});
```

**3.DEVICE REGISTRATION TOKEN:**

Device token is a unique key.Different service gateways has different method to implement and get token.Below is example for firebase device token.On initial startup of your app, the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. 

For Retrieve the current registration token in firebase:

```
 const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
        // user has a device token
    } else {
        // user doesn't have a device token yet
    }
```

For more info:[doc](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/messaging/device-token)

Comment: for device token why firebase service...what if i am using own server.

Comment: you can use react-native-device-token library,and if you have your own service ->then you should implement method for getting token from service documentation.

Comment: does device token is specific to phone or user. As I am new to it so I don't no how it works.I am using device token because in login api which i am using there is a required field of these things so I don't know why these are requiring.

Comment: Device token is app-specific,but not device specific. Device token will be different and unique for multiple apps in same device.

Comment: and what if same user is logged in multiple device with same user name

Comment: Yes,its a different in multiple device with same authentication

Comment: If you have some more query,let me know.or if you found helpful answer , please accept the answer and close question.

Comment: Just a reminder that the `react-native-device-info` library is not supported by managed expo apps. The equivalent library Expo Device (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/device/) does not return the device id.

Answer (score 1):

To get deviceId on expo without ejecting, you can get it by

```
const deviceId = Expo.Constants.deviceId;
```

related link: https://forums.expo.io/t/help-getting-the-deviceid/12670

Comment: Try not to use this constant as it will change if you reinstall the app

Comment: `deviceId` is deprecated and will be remove din Expo SDK 44

Comment: Moris there is any idea about what we can use now ?

Answer (score -2):

Since native code and expo do not mix you might want to try out a package like expo-device. It is quite straight-forward to use. check out the documentation here
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/device/

Comment: the library doesn't provide any function to get the deviceID