# Expo constants deviceId and installationId undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using Expo SDK 35 with expo-constants v7.0.0.

I used to get a value for Constants.deviceId but now it is coming back as undefined.

I Googled and saw that there is meant to be another property called installationId which superseeds this, but this is undefined also.

Can anyone shed any light?  I need a unique ID per device/installation to identify the device on my server, is there any other expo library that can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check https://forums.expo.io/t/constants-deviceid-and-constants-installationid-undefined/36202

Answer (score 0):

`Expo.Constants.deviceId` is deprecated and will be removed in Expo `SDK 44`, we will need to implement our own solution to keep track of device unique identifiers, see my answer here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553627/7944610) it will work for IOS and Android.