# Getting Device Serial Number From Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using Expo to build a React Native app I am using to onboard ios devices.

These are phones going to people who are not technically savy.

So I am building the mobile app to ideally pull the serial number from device info.

I do not see this as an option.

There use to be as I had an app that did something similar not to long ago.

How do I get the serial number?

Answer (score 1):

For Expo IOS theres currently very limited options, since Apple forbids getting private device info.

If all you need is a device unique identifier we will need to create our own unique id see my answer here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553627/7944610).

Answer (score 0):

expo-application (info about the current app), expo-cellular (info about the cell data connection), expo-device (info about the device). There are some sensitive fields like the device’s IMEI that these modules do not attempt to expose.

I don't think you can get serial number due to privacy issues. You can try to use [Notification](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) which generates a unique device token. That can be used in your use-case

**another solution** is
[react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info) - but you need to eject from expo to use it

Comment: There use to be a way to get the serial, as I had an app do something similar. We use the serial to register the device in Jamf, i need to be able to do this remotely.

Comment: Sorry, i just saw your comment about ejecting expo.. unfortunately i need expo for various reasons.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this by using expo?