# How to set Constants.installationId for react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Iam new to react native and expo, while using an expo API in react-native project I got a warning "Constants.installationId has been deprecated in favor of generating and storing your own ID. Implement it using expo-application's androidId on Android and a storage API such as expo-secure-store on iOS
and localStorage on the web. This API will be removed in SDK 44."

And I got a solution for this from [expo forum](https://forums.expo.dev/t/constants-installationid-how-to-implement-it-on-your-own/50003/15)

But I can't figure out how to apply this solution to my project.

Comment: Here is another discussion of same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863644/expo-get-unique-device-id-without-ejecting/68553627#comment121161071_68553627.

You should store generated id SecureStore.

Answer (score -1):

it depends of your cenario. But you can simply implement it on the first page of your application. Depending of your case you'll need to save it on secure local storage if you provide more infos bout your project I could help better.

I'm just newer in react native too, but I can help ya.